# Measure average DC power in Simulink

Tags: simulink

I want to measure power losses of IGBTs and DIODES in a power electronics circuit but I cant find in simulink library a block for AVERAGE DC power.Active & Reactive power blocks are useless because it refers to AC circuits.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question, my solution so far is to use an integral block(I'm using a discrete system) with the external reset enabled, which interfaces to a system clock that goes through a mod block, with whatever interval over which to average the function as the modulus.  This triggers a reset of the running integral every "modulus" time steps.  I'm not quite sure if there's a better way, se

Comment: There is a running mean option if you have the DSP toolbox, http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/dsp/ref/mean.html